# SFINAE with std::is_rvalue_reference for variadic template argument list fails

Tags: sfinae, rvalue-reference, variadic

I try to implement a function taking a variable list of rvalue references. It looks like this:

```
template <
    typename... Args,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction<
        std::is_rvalue_reference<Args>...>::value>
>
void myfunc(Args&&... args)
{ }
```

When I try to call it like this:

```
void doit()
{
    int x;

    myfunc(std::move(x));
}
```

The compiler tells me that he cannot find the function. If i remove the SFINAE check it works.
Do I miss something here, or is the compiler wrong?
I'm using Visual Studio with toolsets v140 and v141.

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Args` is not an rvalue reference, `Args&&` is.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <
    typename... Args,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction<
        std::is_rvalue_reference<Args&&>...>::value>
>
void myfunc(Args&&... args) { }

struct probe {};

int main() {
    probe x;

    // this compiles
    myfunc(std::move(x));

    // this does not
    myfunc(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. I have to correct my knowledge about forwarding references and deduction rules. I tought it is deduced as rvalue reference which is than combined with && and collapsed to Args&& again. But apparently it's not.

Comment: Nice! For things like this `clang` gives very good diagnostic messages (I usually do it with godbolt online compiler research tool).